# How do I parse this response correctly in post man?

Tags: json, parsing, postman

I have tried using the below in postman to parse am array response (further below). for some reason I dont just get the id value. and no mater what array position I enter, I get a type error of

> cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

postman script

```
const response = pm.response.json();
console.log(pm.globals.get("alarm1Id", response.result.alarms[0].id));
```

get request response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "result": {
        "alarms": [
            {
                "id": "C6707LJmR1yTzjYrfoBTxw",
                "name": "Test Alarm1",
                "state": "PURGED",
                "isAssignedToCurrentUser": false,
                "timeOfLastStateChange": "2023-01-20T01:04:38.917Z",
                "type": "NORMAL",
                "associatedCameras": [
                    "4xIx1DMwMLSwMDU2sTA2NdNLTsw1MBASmCLZ_fximWvi_v08agen8bMBAA"
                ],
                "priority": 0,
                "isNoteRequired": false,
                "missedTriggers": 0,
                "timeOfMostRecentAcknowledgement": "2023-01-20T01:02:09.670Z",
                "timeOfMostRecentActivation": "2023-01-20T01:02:02.346Z",
                "timeOfMostRecentPurge": "2023-01-20T01:04:38.917Z",
                "durationOfPreRecording": "PT5S",
                "durationOfPostRecording": "PT1M",
                "digitalOutputsToActivate": []
            },
            {
                "id": "kNJnCVsdQFWzvOeBshTqeg",
                "name": "FR",
                "state": "PURGED",
                "isAssignedToCurrentUser": false,
                "timeOfLastStateChange": "2022-12-01T23:26:41.482Z",
                "type": "NORMAL",
                "associatedCameras": [
                    "49Ix0UsyNU4ySEpN002yTDbSNTFONNW1NLEw001LTkw0NjI2ME-0sNBLTsw1MBASmCLZ_fximWvi_v08agen8bMBAA"
                ],
                "priority": 0,
                "isNoteRequired": false,
                "missedTriggers": 0,
                "timeOfMostRecentAcknowledgement": "2022-07-07T18:21:28.981Z",
                "timeOfMostRecentActivation": "2022-07-06T17:17:09.751Z",
                "timeOfMostRecentPurge": "2022-12-01T23:26:41.482Z",
                "durationOfPreRecording": "PT5S",
                "durationOfPostRecording": "PT1M",
                "digitalOutputsToActivate": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried different list positions . I'm thinking I just don't fully understand that data structure on the response.

Comment: you have a typo, should be  "alarms" instead of  "alamrs"

Comment: Hi Serge, was typo when i wrote it into the info, i have it correct in the actual script, that's my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
response = JSON.parse(responseBody)
```

alarm1Id = response.result.alarms[0].id

I did some digging, I was able to extract id data with the script above